# Jest js Install - getting error -- npm ERR! Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs

I'm trying to install jest using the following command

```
npm i jest --save-dev
```

I'm getting the following error

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "jest" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v8.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v5.6.0

npm ERR! Class constructor  cannot be invoked without 'new'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: What's the node version?

Comment: node v8.11.3 npm v5.6.0

Comment: I just ran the install command and it worked. `+ jest@23.6.0
added 557 packages from 341 contributors and audited 17606 packages in 148.343s
found 0 vulnerabilities`

Comment: Can you please post your package.json?

Comment: {
  "name": "unit-testing-functions",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the presets in your .bablerc with

```
"presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"]
```

Also, try to delete package-lock.json and node_modules, then npm i and try again

Comment: Where do I find the .bablerc file for this project

Comment: You need to add it yourself if you don't have it

Comment: Thanks. The actual problem was with my org firewall. Not allowing me to install any nodes.